# Деструктор при использовании синглтона

Tags: c++

Пусть есть синглтон класс

```
class Singleton {
public:
    static Singleton* Instance();
protected:
    Singleton();
private:
    static Singleton* _instance;
};
```

А реализация такова:

```
Singleton* Singleton::_instance = 0;
Singleton* Singleton::Instance () {
    if (_instance == 0) {
        _instance = new Singleton;
    }
    return _instance;
}
```

Если мы для него опишем деструктор :

```
Singleton :: ~Singleton(){
    delete _instance;
}
```

то получается, что при завершении любой функции(при выходе из области видимости), которая обращалась с сущности синглтон и сохарняла указатель, будет вызывать деструктор, который удалит объект.

Вопрос -  как быть? Реализовывать свой hsared_ptr или что-то подобное внутри деструктора это такой себе вариант,как мне кажется, а терять глобальный объект, который нужен 1 на всё время работы программы вообще нельзя

Comment: Ну вот, в деструкторе **объекта** освобождать член **класса**?! Если вы ну обязательно хотите перед выходом из программы вызвать деструктор для своего синглтона, работайте через ссылку, а не через указатель... И, кстати, никакого вызова деструктора в функции у вас не случится, потому что не для чего его вызывать. Если вы, конечно, не вызовете деструктор руками...

Comment: Почему вы решили, что при выходе из области видимости будет вызываться деструктор? Вы же работаете с указателем.

Comment: Все наоборот: деструктор будет вызван при вызове `delete _instance;`, то бишь никогда в этом коде. При выходе из области видимости указателя на объект вызывает деструктор самого указателя (который ничего не делает), а не объекта, на который тот указывал.

Comment: @user7860670 а почему в таком случае деструктор вызывается очень много раз?
https://onlinegdb.com/ZY9pE8hub

Comment: @SpaceResearcher потому что `delete` приводит к вызову деструктора, в котором снова `delete`, который приводит к вызову деструктора и т.д. Это называется рекурсия, которой быть не должно.

Comment: Зачем удалять объект на выходе из каждой функции если он нужен на всё время работы программы? Вы сами себе проблему придумали.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ а можно так удалять?
    ~Single(){
        std :: cout << "deleted \n";
        auto a = _pointer;
        _pointer = nullptr;
        delete a;
    }

Comment: Те же яйца, только в профиль. Поле `_pointer` содержит указатель на объект, который уже уничтожается деструктором и вы ещё раз вызываете его удаление, которое и так уже в процессе.

Answer (score 2):

Вы зовете `delete` в двух местах, и в обоих местах он лишний. Функция, обращающаяся к синглтону, не должна его звать, потому что кому-то после нее он может понадобиться.

Деструктор синглтона не должен звать `delete`, тут вообще логика задом наперед. `delete` зовет деструктор (и освобождает память), а не наоборот. Если звать `delete` из деструктора, то деструктор позовется дважды, а это - неопределенное поведение.

---

Вообще, это плохой синглтон, как минимум потому что не потокобезопасный. Хороший выглядит так:

```
class Singleton
{
  public:
    static Singleton &Instance()
    {
        static Singleton ret;
        return ret;
    }

  private:
    Singleton();
};
```

И писанины меньше.

Тут деструктор вызывается один раз при выходе из программы (и если вы его напишете, там не нужен никакой `delete`, конечно).

---

Использовать `new` имеет смысл только если вы наоборот хотите, чтобы деструктор синглтона не вызывался на выходе из программы. (Обычно деструкторы не делают ничего такого важного, без чего нельзя закрыть программу, и для скорости может хотеться их не звать.)

Но тогда нужно написать так, чтобы было потокобезопасно:

```
static Singleton &Instance()
{
    static Singleton &ret = *new Instance;
    return ret;
}
```

И опять же, `delete` тут не нужен.

Comment: *"Хороший выглядит так"* - сначала люди делают такие "хорошие" синглетоны, а потом воют, что с ним невозможно тестировать, что конструктор только по-умолчанию, что SIOF/SUOF и т.п.  *"И опять же, delete тут не нужен."* - а потом программа показывает утечки памяти в профилировщике, созданные синглетоном временные файлы остались валяться на диске, а админ не оповещен о выходе приложения...

Comment: @user7860670 Про важные действия в деструкторе - я к тому, что действительно важные вещи обычно делаются не там, потому что деструкторы не зовутся при краше. *"программа показывает утечки памяти в профилировщике"* Проверил, ASAN в нормальных компиляторах (Clang и GCC, то есть :)) такие вещи игнорирует. MSVC не смотрел. *"невозможно тестировать"* Это не значит, что знание про то как их писать нужно скрывать, так мы выращиваем неумелых программистов. Надо и учить писать, и рассказывать почему это вредно.

Comment: *"SIOF/SUOF"* Ну кстати делать их внутри функций помогает против самых популярных случаев SIOF.

Comment: *"Проверил, ASAN в нормальных компиляторах (Clang и GCC, то есть :)) такие вещи игнорирует."* - подписывайтесь в багтрекер https://github.com/google/sanitizers/issues/1485 (иронично, что код там - практически такой же синглетон) и пользуйтесь valgrind. *"не значит, что знание про то как их писать нужно скрывать"* - рекомендации делать синглетон мейерса я отношу к категоирии вредных советов, а не знаний

Comment: От "SIOF/SUOF" оно как бы вообще не защищает, так как принцип "Кто первым встал, того и тапки" работает точно так же, а выяснить, кто там был первым, может быть крайне проблематично.

Comment: @user7860670 По ссылке нет подтверждения, что это баг. Просто какой-то чел удивился текущему поведению. *"От "SIOF/SUOF" оно как бы вообще не защищает"* Защита в том, что объект создается при первом вызове функции, а не в произвольном порядке. Поэтому никогда не будет такого, что один синглтон обращается ко второму, а тот еще не создался.

Comment: @user7860670 Я в целом согласен, что синглтоны не нужны, но есть одно исключение - всякая автоматическая регистрация дочерних классов/модулей/плагинов/... Там без них не сделать.

Comment: *"Просто какой-то чел удивился"* - ну открытый тикет есть, это факт. Скорее просто до него руки не доходят у разрабов, активность в проекте низкая. *"никогда не будет такого"* https://godbolt.org/z/jjYeYdcEa - несмотря на очевидную искусственность этого примера, в реальности оно по такому сценарию может происходить очень даже запросто, только распутывать придется дольше. *"согласен, что синглтоны не нужны"* - я не утверждал, что они не нужны, я только против синглетона мейерса и использования стадии глобальной инициализации вообще

Comment: @user7860670 Опять же, без таких глобальных переменных не работает всякая удобная автоматическая регистрация.